# Bootstrap model show/hide

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have this ajax call upon success i have bootstrap model which is not showing

Here is the code

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('form').submit(function(e){
       var name = $('#name').val();
       var email = $('#email').val();
       var message = $('#message').val();

       var data = 'name=' + name + '&email=' + email + '&message=' + message;

       $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: 'script.php',
        data: data,
        success: $(document)ready(function(){
        $("#myModal").modal('show');
        )
       });
        e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of mistakes and syntax errors in your code

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form').submit(function(e){
       var name = $('#name').val();
       var email = $('#email').val();
       var message = $('#message').val();

       var data = 'name=' + name + '&email=' + email + '&message=' + message;

       $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: 'script.php',
        data: data,
        success: $(document).ready(function(){  //missing . before ready
        $("#myModal").modal("show");
        }) // you was missing } here
       });
        e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
    });
  });
```